# How to center caption in Bootstrap 4 carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I essentially copied the captioned carousel example from the Bootstrap 4 documentation: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

However, I cannot seem to achieve a carousel that only has text, where the text is centered...

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide bg-chrome" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div data-slide-no="0" class="carousel-item item active">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h1>My Carousel</h1>
        ...is not centered!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous slide</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next slide</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Aside from some minor styling, this is what the above code renders:

[image]

As you can see, the text is not centered! Per some other questions I found here on StackOverflow, I tried:

1. Setting `.carousel-caption` to have `margin: 0 auto`
2. Setting `.carousel-caption` to have `position: relative`
3. Setting `.carousel-caption` to have `text-align: center`
4. Wrapping each `.carousel-item` in a `.container` and styling to achieve a centered text

None of the solutions have worked, so I ask you all; **how can I achieve a horizontally centered carousel with only captions?**

Edit: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchp6bg9/9/)

Comment: Would you add a jsfiddle.net or codepen.io to your otherwise very thorough question? :-)

Comment: Updated my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of BS alpha 6, the `.carousel-item` is `display:flex;` which limits some of the positioning you can do with the contents of `carousel-item`. This is a known issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21611

So, one option is to change the active `.carousel-item` is `display:block;`. Then you can simply use `text-center` to center the contents.

```
.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev{
    display:block;
}

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
        <h1>My Carousel</h1> ...is centered!
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">
        <h1>2 Carousel</h1> ...is centered!
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">
        <h1>3 Carousel</h1> ...is centered!
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/ja3h44A7bQ

---

Another option is to simply use the flexbox utils, and change the direction to `flex-column`. Then `align-items-center` can be used...

```
      <div class="carousel-inner text-white" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active align-items-center flex-column p-4">
                <h1>My Carousel</h1> ...is centered!
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item align-items-center flex-column p-4">
                <h1>2 Carousel</h1> ...is centered!
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item align-items-center flex-column p-4">
                <h1>3 Carousel</h1> ...is centered!
            </div>
       </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/9I7voUaDUi

In both cases I've removed the `carousel-caption`. The `carousel-caption` should only be used if you want the text to *overlay* a slide image. There's no reason to use the  'carousel-caption' if there is no image, just put the content inside `carousel-item`.

---

Also see: [Vertically center text in Bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914872/vertically-center-text-in-bootstrap-carousel/45918546#45918546)

Comment: Worth noting that this works in part because you've moved the text from 'carousel-caption' to simply be in 'carousel-item'.  this makes sense because the text is now the content rather than a caption due to removing the image, but since the OP hadn't made that change, it's might not hurt to mention.

Comment: I like this solution. However, if one of the `carousel-item` elements is naturally taller than the rest (e.g. one of the slides has an image or text), the carousel will resize based on the current slide's content. Is there a way to dynamically set the height of the carousel based on the tallest slide, aside from using the CSS `min-height`?

Comment: I think min-height would be the best way as the carousel slides may vary in height.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a combination of the `position:relative;` you were adding on the `.carousel-caption` and the absence of a 'height' value for the `.carousel-item`

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z0cxhgc1/1/

**Update:**
Bootstrap's default carousel automatically takes on the height of the image, and then uses

```
position: absolute;
right: 15%;
bottom: 20px;
left: 15%;
```

to style the caption over the lower center of the image.  without the image's natural height, everything else in the carousel is positioned absolutely, and since the carousel itself has a height of 0, it was showing up 20px above the bottom -- or 20px above and outside of the carousel.

your `position: relative;` style got it showing again because putting it back in the document flow gave the slide element a natural height again, but was conflicting with the other styles in terms of positioning.

Comment: I appreciate it, friend.

Comment: updated the answer with a little more info about why the `min-height` in my fork of your fiddle was needed.  If you don't want to have to set the height, or you prefer to have the text positioned vertically centered instead of aligned to the bottom, those should be fairly straight-forward options, but this would probably be the fewest/smallest changes to get it working

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Add some height to the carousel item so that it does not disappear (since you are not using an image):

```
.carousel-item{
    height:200px;
}
```

Remove:

```
.carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**More detailed answer:**

I believe that your answer can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/). Normally, your captions should be centred, but if not then try adding "text-center" to your "carousel-caption". That should fix it.

An example solution using Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 showing:

- the usage of d-* for hiding and showing text on different device screens and adjusting the display type i.e `d-md-block` means set the display to block on medium devices
- the alignment of text

```css
.bg-chrome {
   background: blue;
 }
 
 .carousel-item{
   height:200px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide bg-chrome" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h3>A carousel caption with text on all device screens and aligned to the center</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block text-left">
        <h3>A carousel caption with text aligned to the left</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block text-right">
        <h3>A carousel caption with text aligned to the right</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>A carousel caption with hidden text on small devices</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous slide</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next slide</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle.
Left and right 15% PLUS text centered let the heading confuse

https://jsfiddle.net/jchp6bg9/10/
Added

```
left:0%; 
right: 0%;
```

to your css code

Answer (score 0):

For carousel with fixed height (e.g.: 400px) this works for me:

```
.carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 150px; // Set relative to your carousel height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-caption{
    background-color: rgb(209, 209, 154);
    top: 30%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.